# Favicon missing on select pages

Tags: browser, cross-browser, favicon

This is the inverse of every favicon question you've ever heard. :-)

I've got my favicon working on all pages and across all browsers, save 1 situation. The icon doesn't show up in Firefox and Google Chrome on my sign in page -- https://fwdvault.com/signin

IE, Opera, and Safari pick it up just fine.

The logic that builds the header is the same for this page as all the others, no code differences.

Compare with any other page on the site -- fwdvault.com

Any ideas? I'm totally stumped.

Comment: Yes, I've cleared the cache. Should've said that up front.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine here *(both with FF3.5 and chromium : some sort of blue @)* ; maybe some problem with your browser's cache ?

Did you try clearing it, and restarting your browser, just to be sure ?

Comment: That's it. Just confirm you're seeing it on the signup page? If users can see it, I'm not going to worry about it. :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine for me.  Perhaps a browser cache issue? Try a good old Control+F5 on the page to force refresh all content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem. My favicon won't show up on any pages in my site in Firefox 3.6 using http; if I go to the same pages using https, the favicon shows up fine. In IE8, Chrome and Safari the favicon shows up fine.

Bookmark, url, tab, all act the same.